How can I check if the incorrect result is from the code?
GM = 394874/10000;
t0 = 0;
t1 = 140;
c = 63286;


geot = D[t[λ], {λ, 2}] + (2 GM)/(
     r[λ] (c^2 r[λ] - 2 GM)) D[
     r[λ], λ] D[t[λ], λ] == 0;
geor = D[r[λ], {λ, 2}] + 
    GM/(c^2 r[λ]^3) (c^2 r[λ] - 2 GM) (D[
       t[λ], λ])^2 - 
    GM/(r[λ] (c^2 r[λ] - 2 GM)) (D[
       r[λ], λ])^2 - (r[λ] - (2 GM)/
       c^2) (D[θ[λ], λ])^2 == 0;
geoth = D[θ[λ], {λ, 2}] + 
    2/r[λ] D[θ[λ], λ] D[
      r[λ], λ] == 0;

incond = {t[0] == 0, t'[0] == 1000000012*10^-9, r[0] == 1, 
   r'[0] == 0, θ[0] == 0, θ'[0] == 628/100 };

sol = NDSolve[{geot, geor, geoth, incond}, {t, 
   r, θ}, {λ, t0, t1}, WorkingPrecision -> 40, 
  MaxSteps -> 10^5]
plot1 = ParametricPlot[
  Evaluate[{r[λ] Cos[θ[λ]], 
     r[λ] Sin[θ[λ]]} /. sol], {λ, t0, 
   t1}, PlotRange -> All, PlotStyle -> Red, MaxRecursion -> 15]


While I increase the value of θ' the period of rotation increases and vice versa.
But physically it should be the inverse. As I increase θ' the particle should become near to the center (The orbitation radius should be smaller).
Is the problem from my code or did I misunderstand the physics role?
Note: The above code is for the normal case and the picture below is for θ'=8.8 which is the case that I'm talking about.

What are you computing?

@yarchik I am drawing the Earth's rotation around the Sun by using the Schwartzchild metric. And I want to change θ' to study how the rotation will be.

You are not sure what is wrong: the code or the equations. It is unlikely that someone here knows what Schwartzchild metric is to be able to help you with equations. After all, this is a Mathematica forum. But you can write your equations in tex format and ask whether you correctly implemented them.

@yarchik geodesics are correct. I don't know if the problem is from some options in the code or if I misunderstood the physics concept of angular velocity.

I don’t understand the meaning of “While I increase the value of θ'”.  θ is       a solution to ODE, not the parameter you can adjust…..

Rule of thumb: the solver for initial value problem of ODE systems built in NDSolve is very robust. If something looks incorrect while no warning is given, the ODE solver should always be the last thing to check, and the problem itself should always be the first thing to check. And in your case, even if we take away all of the options from NDSolve, the output still looks the same, and no warning is generated, all these suggest Mathematica has solved the given problem reliably. So, please double check the problem itself.

As to the physics part, as pointed out @yarchik , it's not that suitable for this site. I'd suggest asking in e.g. https://physics.stackexchange.com/

@A.Kato θ' is the angular velocity and it has an initial value as mentioned above in the code so the value that I'm changing is the initial value of θ' in incond = {t[0] == 0, t'[0] == 1000000012*10^-9, r[0] == 1,     r'[0] == 0, θ[0] == 0, θ'[0] == 628/100 };

I see. You mean you increased initial value of  θ' .

Your geot seems to be different from the corresponding equation (the third equation in Geodesic equation) from Wikipedia Schwarzschild geodesics. Please check.
